# how to get value from list javescript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to extract a value with a specified key. below are the data example;
example = [{'a':0,'b':2,'c':4}]

"results I want : 2"

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of `b`, you would need to use `example[0]['b']`. You need the `[0]` since you also have an array enclosing the object.